Subscriber node doesn't work
I have followed a ROS2 tutorial and generated a subscriber for Turtlesim. With colcon build it was successfully finished but if I try to execute it, it doesn`t work. In the following I copy the complete dialog for the construction of the Node:
samy@ros:~$ ros2 run turtlesim turtlesim_node 
[INFO] [1716587934.376285544] [turtlesim]: Starting turtlesim with node name /turtlesim 
[INFO] [1716587934.383827465] [turtlesim]: Spawning turtle [turtle1] at x=[5.544445], y=[5.544445], theta=[0.000000] ^C
[INFO] [1716588425.581422084] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2) 
samy@ros:~$ cd ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller/ 
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller$ ls draw_circle.py  __init__.py  my_first_node.py  __pycache__
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller$ chmod
+x pose_subscriber.py 
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller$ ls draw_circle.py  __init__.py  my_first_node.py  pose_subscriber.py 
__pycache__ 
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller$ cd ../.. 
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws/src$ code . 
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws/src$ cd 
samy@ros:~$ cd ros2_ws/ 
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws$ colcon build
    --symlink-install Starting >>> my_robot_controller Finished <<< my_robot_controller [1.24s]   

   

Summary: 1 package finished [1.57s] samy@ros:~/ros2_ws$ source ~/.bashrc samy@ros:~/ros2_ws$ ros2 run my_robot_controller pose_subscriber  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/samy/ros2_ws/install/my_robot_controller/lib/my_robot_controller/pose_subscriber", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('my-robot-controller', 'console_scripts', 'pose_subscriber')())   File "/home/samy/ros2_ws/build/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller/pose_subscriber.py", line 18, in main
    node = PoseSubscriberNode()   File "/home/samy/ros2_ws/build/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller/pose_subscriber.py", line 11, in __init__
    Pose, "/turtle1/pose", self.pose_callback, 10) AttributeError: 'PoseSubscriberNode' object has no attribute 'pose_callback' [ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1 samy@ros:~/ros2_ws$ ros2 run my_robot_controller pose_subscriber Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/samy/ros2_ws/install/my_robot_controller/lib/my_robot_controller/pose_subscriber", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('my-robot-controller', 'console_scripts', 'pose_subscriber')())   File "/home/samy/ros2_ws/build/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller/pose_subscriber.py", line 18, in main
    node = PoseSubscriberNode()   File "/home/samy/ros2_ws/build/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller/pose_subscriber.py", line 11, in __init__
    Pose, "/turtle1/pose", self.pose_callback, 10) AttributeError: 'PoseSubscriberNode' object has no attribute 'pose_callback' [ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1 samy@ros:~/ros2_ws$

This is my code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from turtlesim.msg import Pose

class PoseSubscriberNode(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("pose_subscriber")
        self.pose_subscriber_ = self.create_subscription(
            Pose, "/turtle1/pose", self.pose_callback, 10)

        def pose_callback(self, msg: Pose):
            self.get_logger().info(str(msg))

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = PoseSubscriberNode()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    rclpy.shutdown()

This is the setup.py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

package_name = 'my_robot_controller'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['test']),
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='samy',
    maintainer_email='samy@todo.todo',
    description='TODO: Package description',
    license='TODO: License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            "test_node = my_robot_controller.my_first_node:main",
            "draw_circle = my_robot_controller.draw_circle:main",
            "pose_subscriber = my_robot_controller.pose_subscriber:main"
        ],
    },
)


This looks like a simple indentation issue. If you carefully included your code in a code block it would be clearer.

The pose definition function callback is within the class init. Try moving it out (remove the indent).
